# concurrent request limit exceeded

Tags: governorlimits, callout

I am getting below eroor intermittently. I know the reason for this error as I read on docs but could not find out what I am supposed to do to avoid it, what might be the resolution.

> Error - "Unable to Process Request   Concurrent requests limit 
>   exceeded"
>
> "To protect all customers from excessive usage and Denial of Service
>   attacks, we limit the number of long-running requests that are
>   processed at the same time by an organization. Your request has been
>   denied because this limit has been exceeded by your organization.
>   Please try your request again later."

Comment: When is this happening, what action is being done and what type of request is going on ? Including information like this in your question will allow us to answer you with much more detail and relevance.

Comment: Hi Sam, sorry for posting incomplete information. Issue is resolved however i just wanted to apologize for lack of information I posted. I shall take care in future.

Comment: That's all right. Would you be able to share how you've analysed or solved this in an answer ? That'd help others with the same problem in the future.

Answer (score -2):

this errors could be caused by users using the same login and password in eclipse, you should avoid doing that.
Other than this you should wait a while before you could work again